# Asynchronous mapFold

Tags: asynchronous, f#, fold

For the following example, `Array.mapFold` produces the result `([|1; 4; 12|], 7)`.

```
let mapping s x = (s * x, s + x)

[| 1..3 |]
|> Array.mapFold mapping 1
```

Now suppose our mapping is asynchronous.

```
let asyncMapping s x = async { return (s * x, s + x) }
```

I am able to create `Array.mapFoldAsync` for the following to work.

```
[| 1..3 |]
|> Array.mapFoldAsync asyncMapping 1
|> Async.RunSynchronously
```

Is there a succinct way to achieve this without creating `Array.mapFoldAsync`?

I am asking as a way to learn other techniques - my attempts using Array.fold were horrible.

Comment: It seems to me that you are looking for something like [AsyncSeq](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharp.Control.AsyncSeq). Have you had a look at it?

Comment: try Asynchronous sequences libraries. `AsyncSeq` and `Hopac.Streams` both have great F# facade. `Akka.Streams` and `TPL DataFlow` are also great but lack any F# interop (good old C#-style code).

Comment: Thanks for the library suggestions. I have looked at AsyncSeq some time ago, but didn't think to check there this time. Using AsyncSeq.foldAsync seems the closest I can find to a reasonable solution without writing your own mapFoldAsync.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it would generally be of much benefit to combine `mapFold` with an `Async` function, because the expected result is a tuple `('values * 'accumulator)`, but using an `Async` function will at best give you an `Async<'values * 'accumulator>`.  Consider the following attempt to make `Array.mapFold` work with `Async`:

```
let mapping s x = async { 
    let! s' = s
    let! x' = x
    return (s' * x', s' + x') 
}

[| 1..3 |]
|> Array.map async.Return
|> Array.mapFold mapping (async.Return 1)
```

Even this doesn't work, because of the type mismatch:  `The type ''a * Async<'b>' does not match the type 'Async<'c * 'd>'`.

You may also have noticed that while there is an `Array.Parallel.map`, there's no `Array.Parallel.fold` or `Array.Parallel.mapFold`.  If you try to write your own `mapFoldAsync`, you may see why.  The mapping part is pretty easy, just partially apply `Array.map` and compose with `Async.Parallel`:

```
let mapAsync f = Array.map f >> Async.Parallel
```

You can implement an async `fold` as well, but since each evaluation depends on the previous result, you can't leverage `Async.Parallel` this time:

```
let foldAsync f state array =
    match array |> Array.length with
    | 0 -> async.Return state
    | length ->
        async {
            let mutable acc = state
            for i = 0 to length - 1 do
                let! value = f acc array.[i]
                acc <- value
            return acc
        }
```

Now, when we try to combine these to build a `mapFoldAsync`, it becomes apparent that we can't leverage parallel execution on the mapping anymore, because both the values and the accumulator can be based on the result of the previous evaluation.  That means our `mapFoldAsync` will be a modified 'foldAsync', not a composition of it with `mapAsync`:

```
let mapFoldAsync (f: 's -> 'a -> Async<'b * 's>) (state: 's) (array: 'a []) =
    match array |> Array.length with
    | 0 -> async.Return ([||], state)
    | length ->
        async {
            let mutable acc = state
            let results = Array.init length <| fun _ -> Unchecked.defaultof<'b>
            for i = 0 to length - 1 do
                let! (x,y) = f acc array.[i]
                results.[i] <- x
                acc <- y
            return (results, acc)
        }
```

While this will give you a way to do a `mapFold` with an async mapping function, the only real benefit would be if the mapping function did something with high-latency, such as a service call.  You won't be able to leverage parallel execution for speed-up.  If possible, I would suggest considering an alternative solution, based on your real-world scenario.

Comment: Thank you, this explains the situation well. My application is a web site and the mapping function makes several calls to SQL Server. It seems that having a mapFoldAsync function is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

Without external libraries (I recommend to try `AsyncSeq` or `Hopac.Streams`)
you could do this:

```
let mapping s x = (fst s * x, snd s + x) |> async.Return

module Array = 
    let mapFoldAsync folderAsync (state: 'state) (array: 'elem []) = async {
        let mutable finalState = state
        for elem in array do
            let! nextState = folderAsync finalState elem
            finalState <- nextState
        return finalState
    }

[| 1..4 |]
|> Array.mapFoldAsync mapping (1,0)
|> Async.RunSynchronously
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm not opposed to using an external library. AsyncSeq looks like an ideal place for mapFoldAsync, but it has not been implemented yet. A half reasonable result can be achieved using AsyncSeq.foldAsync though. The Hopac library is a bit beyond where I want to take my project and I did not notice mapFold functionality.